# input filename as caption in listing

Tags: macros, captions, external-files, code

I'm working on the following piece of code

```
\newcommand{\mycin}[1]{% new command for icluding piece of code from external files
  \lstinputlisting{#1}
}
```

I want to add a caption that reflects the name of the actual filename included by the command, i tryed something like

```
\newcommand{\mycin}[1]{% new command for icluding piece of code from external files
  \lstinputlisting[caption=\caption{#1}]{#1}
}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\mycin}[1]{% new command for icluding piece of code from external files
  \lstinputlisting[caption={#1}]{#1}
}
```

but both solutions do not works, there is a way to automate the generation of a caption in a newcommand?

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: And always state what and how it "doesn't work", i.e. the error you get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your attempt would actually work for file names without special characters like `_`, `^`, `&`, `$` etc. which have special meaning in (La)TeX.

You can turn them back to normal characters using `\detokenize` (which requires e-TeX, i.e. a LaTeX compiler which is less than a few years old, and not the Science Workplace version). (There is also a non-e-TeX way)

You need `tt` font to display these characters correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\mylisting}[2][]{%
    \lstinputlisting[caption={\texttt{\detokenize{#2}}},#1]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\mylisting{foo.c}

\mylisting[frame=rlbt,language=C]{foo_bar.c}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

From http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings#Settings

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{  
    caption=\lstname
}
\begin{document}

    \lstinputlisting{foo.c}

    \lstinputlisting[frame=rlbt,language=C]{foo_bar.c}

\end{document}
```

Same output, but without Macros.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always better to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. This makes the answer more clear.

Comment: user @927589452 would like to add this remark: I would still suggest combining both answers and use  `\lstset{caption=\texttt{\lstname}}` to prevent 'special characters' from breaking the document