# Command to insert filename in caption of a listing

Tags: macros, listings, captions, external-files

I would like to have a command to insert listings that contain the filename in the caption. This works well as long as there is no "_" etc. in the filename.

I also tried the suggestion from a previous Thread ([input filename as caption in listing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34391/input-filename-as-caption-in-listing)):

```
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\mylisting}[2][]{%
\lstinputlisting[caption={\texttt{\detokenize{#2}}},#1]{#2}%}
```

This works quite well, but fails if I want to insert a `listoflistings` and have included a file that contains an underscore.

```
\lstlistoflistings
```

Looking at the `.lol` file shows that the `listoflistings` command included the following line:

```
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {5.1}\texttt {test_file.cpp}}{36}{lstlisting.5.1}
```

I think the problem is that it does not contain the `\detokenize` command.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add `\protect` in front of `\detokenize`

```
\newcommand{\mylisting}[2][]{%
  \lstinputlisting[caption={\texttt{\protect\detokenize{#2}}},#1]{#2}}
```

The `\protect` command will do nothing when the caption is typeset in the text, but will make LaTeX write it unchanged in the `.lol` file.