# How to use \lstinline inside figure environment's caption argument

Tags: listings, captions, python

Here is the code that I have (I have removed parts which I think are not relevant):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}

% Python style for highlighting
\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{frame=shadowbox,
  language=Python,
  ...
}}

% Python environment
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]
{
\pythonstyle
\lstset{#1}
}
{}

% Python for inline
\newcommand{\pythoninline}[1]{{\pythonstyle\lstinline!#1!}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{python}
def function_name():
    ...
\end{python}
\caption{Definition of the function_name function.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What I would like to do is to use the command \pythoninline inside the figure caption argument. This does not work:

```
\caption{Definition of the \pythoninline{function_name} function.}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Listing of a file with underscores in its name/path](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35204/5764); [Command to insert filename in caption of a listing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99649/5764)

Comment: Thanks, I solved it this way:

\caption{Definition of the {\protect \pythoninline{function_name}} function.}